# Is it possible to use an if statement on choice type column in MS List conditional formatting?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

Apologies this is my first question so I will summarize the issue as best as possible.

On the list I have created below in the progress column I created a drop down option using choice type. I have 3 options, completed - in progress - overdue. I would like to be able when clicking on completed to remove the red conditional formatting on the Due column which shows red when the date is past.

I thought I could do a simple if statement using 'completed' as the statement to change the formatting but it is not working.

Is my approach to complex?

[image: list]

The json in Due column;

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "box-sizing": "border-box",
    "padding": "0 2px",
    "overflow": "hidden",
    "text-overflow": "ellipsis"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": {
      "operator": ":",
      "operands": [
        {
          "operator": "==",
          "operands": [
            "@currentField",
            ""
          ]
        },
        "",
        {
          "operator": ":",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "<",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "Date()",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": "toDateString()",
                      "operands": [
                        "@currentField"
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "operator": "Date()",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": "toDateString()",
                      "operands": [
                        "@now"
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgDarkRed sp-css-borderColor-WhiteFont sp-field-fontSizeMedium sp-css-color-WhiteFont",
            {
              "operator": ":",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "==",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": "Date()",
                      "operands": [
                        {
                          "operator": "toDateString()",
                          "operands": [
                            "@currentField"
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "operator": "Date()",
                      "operands": [
                        {
                          "operator": "toDateString()",
                          "operands": [
                            "@now"
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgOrange sp-css-borderColor-WhiteFont sp-field-fontSizeMedium sp-css-color-WhiteFont",
                {
                  "operator": ":",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": ">",
                      "operands": [
                        {
                          "operator": "Date()",
                          "operands": [
                            {
                              "operator": "toDateString()",
                              "operands": [
                                "@currentField"
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          "operator": "Date()",
                          "operands": [
                            {
                              "operator": "toDateString()",
                              "operands": [
                                "@now"
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgGreen sp-css-borderColor-WhiteFont sp-field-fontSizeMedium sp-css-color-WhiteFont",
                    ""
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "txtContent": "@currentField.displayValue"
}
```

Comment: Can you share the current column formatting JSON you are using for "Due" column? I will provide the update JSON based on "Progress" choice column.

Comment: Just added above - thank you.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Online/Microsoft Lists or SharePoint 2019?

Comment: I'm using MS Lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using JSON like below:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "box-sizing": "border-box",
    "padding": "0 2px",
    "overflow": "hidden",
    "text-overflow": "ellipsis"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(Number(@currentField) == 0 || [$Progress] == 'Completed', '',if(@currentField < @now, 'sp-css-backgroundColor-BgDarkRed sp-css-borderColor-WhiteFont sp-field-fontSizeMedium sp-css-color-WhiteFont', if(@currentField == @now, 'sp-css-backgroundColor-BgOrange sp-css-borderColor-WhiteFont sp-field-fontSizeMedium sp-css-color-WhiteFont', if(@currentField > @now,'sp-css-backgroundColor-BgGreen sp-css-borderColor-WhiteFont sp-field-fontSizeMedium sp-css-color-WhiteFont',''))))"
  },
  "txtContent": "@currentField.displayValue"
}
```

Where `[$Progress]` is an **internal name** of your choice column in SharePoint list in this format: `[$InternalNameOfColumn]`.

You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Output**:

[image]

**Related read**: [SharePoint JSON formatting: Check if date & time column is blank/empty](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/06/20/sharepoint-json-formatting-check-if-date-and-time-column-is-blank-empty/)

Comment: Thank you for this and the learning.

Comment: Okay after researching a bit I managed to change the JSON to something a little different. Based on your help so thank you.

The choice of internal names seems random to me. I thought the style convention was to UNICODE the name I use but for some reason its using field_5.... I'll investigate more on this.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the JSON:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "box-sizing": "border-box",
    "padding": "0 2px",
    "overflow": "hidden",
    "text-overflow": "ellipsis"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": {
      "operator": ":",
      "operands": [
        {
          "operator": "==",
          "operands": [
            "[$field_4]",
            "Completed"
          ]
        },
        "sp-field-fontSizeMedium sp-css-color-WhiteText",
        "sp-field-fontSizeMedium sp-css-color-BlackText sp-field-bold"
      ]
    }
  },
  "txtContent": "[$field_6.displayValue]"
}
```

The result now removes the end date when I change in progress to 'Completed'.

[image]